# CSV calculation with Python. Get data from list

Tags: python

Input txt:

```
May 2014, 156
May 2013, 556
May 2013, 651
```

I add this data to `input.csv` file:

```
import csv

with open("text_file.txt") as inputFile:
    for line in inputFile:
        vars = [line.strip().split(",") for line in inputFile]
        print vars
        #set True if you want to export input as csv file
        convert_to_csv = True
        if convert_to_csv == True:
            with open('input.csv', 'w') as fp:
                a = csv.writer(fp, delimiter=',')
                data = [['Text', 'Count']] + vars
                a.writerows(data)
```

How can I get variables from my `vars` and add 10 (example: 156 + 10) to my 'Count' value?

**print vars output:**

```
[['May 2013', 156], ['May 2013', 556]]
```

Count after calculation = Count + 10 and I want to write output also to csv file (output.csv) with header `['Text', 'Count after calc']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactoring a bit:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv

with open('text_file.txt') as input_file:
    csv_data = []

    for row in csv.reader(input_file, delimiter=','):
        csv_data += [[row[0], int(row[1].strip()) + 10]]

    convert_to_csv = True

    if convert_to_csv:
        with open('input.csv', 'w') as output_file:
            csv_file = csv.writer(output_file, delimiter=',')
            csv_file.writerow(['Text', 'Count'])

            for row in csv_data:
                csv_file.writerow(row)
```

For what you've described it's working well. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to parse the string into an integer, and add 10 to it.

```
vars = [line.strip().split(",") for line in inputFile]
vars = [[v[0],int(v[1])+10] for v in vars]
#             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
print vars
```

Note that this is not a complete code, you will have to perform a few more checks, like what if the second item is not an integer? Upon splitting on `,`, what if the number of items is not equal to 2 ?